# Why do I have two different cookies _ga between my domain and my subdomain ? GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, event-tracking

I would like to track my domain and my subdomain in the same property GA4. Normally, GA4 does this automatically but it doesn't work for me. When I check cookies, I have different values for the cookie _ga between my domain and my subdomain and i don't know why.

However, I have set up my domains in GA4 so that they are automatically linked. So, I'm losing attribution data because Google analytics considers this to be a new visitor when he comes in my subdomain.

Thanks for your help !

I have the same GTM for track my domain and my subdomain but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I found this link to be very helpfull - https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/subdomain-tracking-with-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already looked at the article but it's about multi-domain. My problem is about subdomain. The article mentions automatic tracking for subdomain with GA4 but there isn't details for my problem.